# Question concerning Galois Fields( GF(p) notation)

Tags: galois-theory

I've just been starting to learn about Fields and encountered Galois Fields today: Here, the question arises to me, whether there exists only one field with 15 elements, meaning that $GF(16)^{*}$ denotes only one field. How can one understand the GF() notation in general, does it denote a set of fields or something like that? (I know that my question must sound very stupid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no field with 15 elements, in contrary to 16.

$GF(p^k)$, the field with $p^k$ elements, is the splitting field of $x^{p^k}-x\in \Bbb{F}_p[x]$, it is unique up to isomorphism, concretely it is $\Bbb{F}_p[x]/(f(x))$ for any polynomial $f\in \Bbb{F}_p[x]$ irreducible of degree $k$.

$\Bbb{F}_p[x]/(f(x))$ is the quotient of a polynomial ring by an ideal, similar to that $\Bbb{C}=\Bbb{R}[i]=\Bbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1)$.

Comment: so when I say THE GF(16), this is an ambiguous statement since there are several field with 16 elements?

Comment: They are all isomorphic. You can do most reasoning without choosing a particular $f$, but in the crytography algorithms you often need to assume you are given some $f$. Sometimes you'll want that it is a primitive polynomial, ie. that its root has order $p^k-1$ in the field.

Comment: And if I'm asked to find a generator of GF(16), does it suffice to find a generator of one of the isomorphic fields? (Conversely, for GF(16)*, does it suffice to find a generator of one of the isomorphic groups?) (thanks a lot for your help!)

Comment: Generator as field is more or less the same as finding some $f$, generator of $GF(16)^*$ means finding an element of order $15$ more or less the same as finding some primitive polynomial. Personally I almost never looked at a particular $f$, just proved that it exists, but when implementing algorithms in cryptography it is a bit different.